# The scroll wheels on all of my mice are unresponsive, how can I fix this?

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll

I've tried a few different mice and all exhibit the same issue:

**Only about two fifths of the "ticks" from each mouse's scroll wheel actually do anything.**

Distressingly, it seems to be random. Sometimes, I'll get a wonderful string of three or four ticks in a row that work; other times, seven or eight ticks in a row do nothing. All of the mice I've tried work perfectly on my Windows netbook and on a friend's Macbook.

What do I need to configure to make my scroll wheels behave?

One of the mice is brand new, and all the mice are from Logitech or Microsoft, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I've seen this behavior now on every Ubuntu 12.04 workstation I've used. I'm guessing it's an X windows problem. They don't seem to be polling the mouse scroll event often enough.